# Could defining an empty array be a cause of undefined behavior even if the array is not used?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a huge a source code which rarely cause an undefined behavior (segmentation fault). I tried to track the cause but it was difficult since the undefined behavior is rarely happened. I made a review on the source code and I found that it contains a definition of an empty array but is not used at all in the source code.

```
struct any array[] = {};
```

I know that defining an empty array is not allowed in C. But I'm not sure if this could be a cause of undefined behavior ,especially that the array is not used.

Does defining an empty array could be a cause of an undefined behavior even if the array is not used?

Comment: That shouldn't compile in C.  Since it is a compiler extension if it compiles at all, you'll have to look at the compiler documentation to know what it does.  It is unlikely to be undefined behaviour if the compiler accepts it, though.  So, the chances are you'd be 'OK', but if it isn't used, why not simply remove it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I remove it but I want to be sure if it was the cause of the UB

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was the source of the UB.  Look for something else.

Comment: Is that a local variable on stack or global? Have you double checked that code never writes into the array?

Comment: @Rohan. it s global defined and it's static defined. And there is no code that use it or  write/read it

Comment: I don't think that code is cause of UB. Without stack dump/crash report its hard to guess.

Comment: Suggest you to run purify and track of the cause of memory leaks/ABR/ABW. This will help you track the rare occurrence of seg fault.

Comment: valgrind is your friend

Answer (score 1):

You should try running your program under control of the `valgrind` memory checker.

`valgrind` runs many kinds of checks on memory accesses and can help track invalid memory references, including those that do not cause visible problems most of the time but may trigger a crash in some circumstances.

Comment: Absolutely this.  Quit guessing and hoping.  Use a tool that actually identifies memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed (for example, attempting to write to a read-only location, or to overwrite part of the operating system).

Thus, in your case, you are not accessing variable and as such the cause of error should be something else.

Answer (score 0):

With undefined behaviour, anything is possible. You should fix this line to comply with the C Standard.  Then if the segmentation fault happens again, you'll know the problem still exists.

(Yes this is a short answer but there is nothing else to be said).